# Time-evolution state of Hamiltonian with reversed sign

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Suppose we evolve from an initial state $\rho_0$ under a given time-dependent Hamiltonian $H(t)$ (time-independent Hamiltonian is also fine) and obtained the fully time-evolved state $\rho_1(T)$. Suppose we have evolved the same initial state under $-H(t)$. Is there anything we can say about this evolved state in terms of $\rho_1(T)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's write your state $\rho$ as:
$$|\rho\rangle = \sum_n a_n |n\rangle$$

where the basis $\{ |n\rangle \}$ is such that
$$H|n\rangle = E_n|n\rangle$$

the in the Schrodinger picture ($\hbar=1$):

$$|n(t)\rangle=e^{-iE_n t} |n\rangle$$

and
$$|\rho(t)\rangle = \sum_n a_n e^{-iE_n t} |n\rangle$$

If your new Hamiltonian $H'$ is $H'=-H$ then you can keep the same basis $\{ |n\rangle \}$ but $E'_n=-E_n$. Then $H'$-determined evolution

$$|\rho(t) \rangle = \sum_n a_n e^{+iE_n t} |n\rangle$$

So $$|\rho(t) \rangle_{H'}=|\rho(-t) \rangle_H$$

This is all you can say I believe (well, if all $a_n$ were real, you could say $\rho_1=(\rho)^*$ in some sense). However I should also mention that physically speaking, inverting the Hamiltonian might not always be a healthy thing to do, as you might in some cases realize that your ground state not defined anymore.